# Неотображение картинки

Tags: веб-программирование, html, javascript

В общем, есть форма, в которой я выбираю картинку и пишу к ней название, потом создаётся новая страница с моим материалом, там название и ссылка на картинку на сервере. Перехожу я по этой ссылке, а картинки нет, но в фтп-менеджере есть, беру я ссылку на эту картинку ещё раз и дописываю к ней всякие буковки потом их стираю перехожу и всё работает. Что за мистика?

Вот пример: http://fletbit.com/load/16-1-0-377 - там под кнопкой (сохранить вКонтакте) есть ссылка: http://wepeop... в общем, скопируйте и вставьте в адресную строку и перейдите. А потом проделайте то же, что и я. Что за мистика?

Answer (score 1):

GET -Ssed 'http://wepeople.ru/pics/adminban.jpg'
GET http://wepeople.ru/pics/adminban.jpg --> **403 Forbidden**
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 17 Apr 2011 18:21:39 GMT
Content-Length: 2217
Content-Type: text/html

ой, форматирование поплыло :(
При использовании "Отформатированный текст" почему то игнорируется выделение жирным :(
В общим по не понятным причинам, у вас сервер таки отдаёт картинку, но не с HTTP 200, а 403 (Forbidden) броузер, прочитав ошибочный код, даже не пытается отобразить картинку.
Да, и было бы еще хорошо Content-Type выводить соответcвующий.

Comment: Что это может значить и как с этим бороться?

Comment: А этого я уже не знаю, кода серверного ж мне не видно.
Разработчику должно быть виднее. Дело в серверном скрипте на который повешан реврайт, имхо. А дальше, не видя код, я не знаю чем помочь

Comment: "Отформатированный" текст снимает любое другое форматирование.